# Can't build android project because ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-support-library

I'm following the training on the developer.android.com site and when I arrived at the Building your first app / Starting another activity section I failed:

I've added the android-support-v7-appcompat library according to this site describes: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res

Where I select the libraries for an android project (Properties of the project / Android / Library) I clicked the add button, selected the project library (first picture), and after I pressed ok the project didn't build.

Before (everything is ok)
[image: Before click ok]

After
[image: Somehow it failed when I ok'd the window.]

Before all this... I was somehow able to build the project, press the Play, but it unfortunately stopped (crashed) on my device immediately after starting. And the console said:

```
[2014-07-23 15:06:45 - android-support-v7-appcompat] Could not find android-support-v7-appcompat.apk!
```

and that was the point when I started investigating the problem... yet unsuccessfully.

My question is, why "deactivating" the library after I check again?

Comment: try to restart eclipse then remove the library after that all add library  again hope helps

Comment: Thank you, but didn't help. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The library project should be placed on the same drive with your workspace. the referencing project was in the same eclipse workspace as the library project.

Comment: Yeah, that can be a problem since I have my proj. and lib. on two different drives.

Now I'm moving eclipse...

Comment: +1000.  Wasted a day on this, problem was that the lib. was on a different drive.  Android development seems to kludgy, why can't someone the size of Google be on top of this?

Answer (score 3):

You should make a copy of appcompat-v7 and put it in your workspace, then have all the projects just reference it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem : using GIT, my project was located on a server :

> ```
> \\BOB\Volume_1\GIT\Android\ICS
> ```

So i had to create a clone of my GIT repository on the same drive than my worspace :

> ```
> D:\WSpaces\Android -> my workspace where is located android-support-v7-appcompat
> D:\WSpaces\GIT     -> the GIT clone repository
> ```

I probably could have shared the *android-support-v7-appcompat* on my repository, not tested...